# Printer is printing from Asp.net development but not printing from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to print barcode labels from and asp.net application to a Zebra barcode label printer.I have created .txt files with asp.net code and these files are printing fine from development environment.but after publishing IIS it is not printing

I have created below code to write .txt file using below code

```
    Using con

                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                    Using StringWriter
                        StringWriter.WriteLine("CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~")
                        StringWriter.WriteLine("^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ")
                        While dr.Read()
                            Dim linex As String = "^FD>;" & dr.Item("BARCODEVALUE") & "^FS"
                            StringWriter.WriteLine("^XA")
                            StringWriter.WriteLine("^MMT")
                            StringWriter.WriteLine("^PW406")
                            StringWriter.WriteLine("^LL0203")
                            StringWriter.WriteLine("^LS0")
                            StringWriter.WriteLine("^BY3,3,82^FT51,113^BCN,,Y,N")
                            StringWriter.WriteLine(linex)
                            StringWriter.WriteLine("^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ")
                        End While
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
```

```
Then below code to print the textfile by calling the cmd shell 

 <pre> Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        With proc.StartInfo
            .FileName = "cmd.exe"
            .Arguments = _shellcmd
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        End With

        proc.Start()
```

where _shellcmd is

```
Dim shellcommand As String = "/C copy " & barcodefile + " lpt1"
```

This is all working,printing the labels but when i publish to IIS it is printing nothing.I have added default pool users to the printer which is connected in the server system

I need to print labels from asp.net application on Zebra bar code printer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use TcpClient if your Zebra is connected through a print server.

```
using System.IO
using System.Net.Sockets
...

Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient()
tcpClient.Connect(printerIpAddress, printerPortNumber)

Using writer = New StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream())
  writer.Write(zplString)
End Using
```

Comment: Hi UNOPARATOR, Thank you for your response.The printer is connected to server using USB cables and i assigned LPT1 port by sharing the printer and using "net use \\network\printername lpt1"  command.Not by a print server.So there is no IP address for the printer

Comment: You can try the Zebra's SDK to print to USB directly. [Link](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Get-USB-connection-response-slowly-when-using-Link-OS-SDK?language=en_US). Although it is in C# you can use an online converter [like this one](https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/) to make it VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it helped me lot, I convert my Zebra to a generic text printer and sent the CPL commands to the printer

Comment: I'm glad that it worked out for you. You might want to mark this as the answer to your question, or you can post your own answer if it is very different from what I posted, so that others might benefit from it in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I got a lead from your answer, so i marked it as the answer